# free list allocator header metadata

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

I'm trying to implement a free list memory allocator and I'm struggling on what the header metadata should hold.
I see most examples and implementations just hold the size of the payload being allocated but I find it not sufficient.

For example say our interface for allocating is:

```cpp
void* Allocate(const std::size_t size, const std::size_t alignment);
```

For simplictly let's assume our pool starting address is @`0x0`.
If our `Header` would only hold size information then it would be defined as follows:

```cpp
struct Header {
  std::size_t size;
};
```

With that we can say `sizeof(Header) = 4` and `alignof(Header) = 4` (Assuming we're on x32).

Now let's assume that we're allocating a double as follows:

```cpp
Allocate(sizeof(double), alignof(double));
```

This is equal to saying we want to allocate block of size `8` and alignment of `8`.
Now if we were to place our `Header` at the start of our pool @`0x0` then our allocated block wouldn't be aligned to `8`, so what we actually need to do is to allocate the new block @`0x08` and have the `Header` @`0x04` as follows:

```
[_ _ _ _ X X X X Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y _ _ _ ...]
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F G H I ...]
```

Where `X` denotes `Header` and `Y` denotes the allocated block for our `double`.
This way not only our allocated block is aligned but the `Header` as-well.

Now as you can see we skipped 4 bytes at the beginning so we could align both the `Header` and the allocated block to the right alignment.

My problem is when we wish to de-allocate tis block we can't get back those 4 bytes and we'll lose them forever.

For example say our interface for de-allocating is:

```cpp
void* Deallocate(void* ptr);
```

If we would deallocate the allocated block previously like so:

```cpp
Deallocate((void*)0x08);
```

Then we couldn't give back to our free list a free block with these 4 bytes at the beginning as padding.

My implementation use a LIFO policy insertion order for the free list so `Deallocate` is implemented as follows:

```cpp
void* Deallocate(void* ptr) {
    Chunk* chunk = reinterpret_cast<Chunk*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(ptr) - sizeof(Header));
    chunk->m_Size = reinterpret_cast<Header*>(chunk)->m_Size;
    chunk->m_Next = m_Head;
    m_Head = chunk;
}
```

So the last block de-allocated is the first block at the free list header.
Now you can notice that the starting address of the free block is

```cpp
Chunk* chunk = reinterpret_cast<Chunk*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(ptr) - sizeof(Header));
```

Which means for the invocation above to de-allocate `(void*)0x8` we would get a free block starting @`0x04` meaning we skipped the 4 bytes and we could never get them again leading to very bad fragmentation problems that won't dissappear.

So I guess I'm missing something that I don't understand. I think this problem can be solved if the `Header` would hold `padding` information as-well and then everything could be de-allocated properly, but it's extra memory waste and beyond that I don't see implementation of free list allocated where `Header` stores padding.

You could argue the size of the `Header` is the size of the allocated block + padding, but that won't help me solve how many bytes from the starting address of the `Header` I need to go backwards to retrieve these padding bytes so this block could be fully de-allocated back to the free list.
In our example if we were to store inside `Header` this information then the `Header` would store not `8` bytes but `12` bytes (8 + 4), and when I `Deallocate((void*)0x08);` I wouldn't be able to figure out how many bytes to decrement from `Header` address to get back those 4 padding bytes back.

I guess I'm not understanding something here and I would be glad if someone could help me understand what I'm not understanding..

**Update:**

Here's the current `Allocate` implementation with the described problem above:

```cpp
void* FreeListAllocator::Allocate(const std::size_t size, const std::size_t alignment)
{
    Chunk* chunk = m_Head;
    void* currentAddress = reinterpret_cast<char*>(chunk) + sizeof(Header);
    std::size_t space = chunk->m_Size;
    std::align(alignment, size, currentAddress, space);
    std::size_t padding = reinterpret_cast<char*>(currentAddress) - reinterpret_cast<char*>(chunk) - sizeof(Header);
    while (size + padding > chunk->m_Size)
    {
        chunk = chunk->m_Next;
        if (chunk == nullptr)
            break;
        currentAddress = reinterpret_cast<char*>(chunk) + sizeof(Header);
        space = chunk->m_Size;
        std::align(alignment, size, currentAddress, space);
        padding = reinterpret_cast<char*>(currentAddress) - reinterpret_cast<char*>(chunk) - sizeof(Header);
    }

    if (chunk == nullptr)
        return nullptr;

    m_Head = reinterpret_cast<Chunk*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(chunk) + sizeof(Header) + size + padding);
    m_Head->m_Size = chunk->m_Size - (size + padding + sizeof(Header));
    m_Head->m_Next = nullptr;

    Header* header = reinterpret_cast<Header*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(chunk) + padding);
    header->m_Size = size;

    return reinterpret_cast<char*>(chunk) + sizeof(Header);
}
```

Note that my free list allocator allocate a memory region of size `X` at construct time and the whole memory region allocated by `malloc` is considered a single block. Later when a few allocation and de-allocations are done the free list starting to become more than one element:

```cpp
FreeListAllocator(const std::size_t size, bool resizeable)
    : m_Size(size), m_Head(nullptr)
{
    m_StartAddress = ::operator new(size);
    m_Head = reinterpret_cast<Chunk*>(m_StartAddress);
    m_Head->m_Size = size - sizeof(Header);
    m_Head->m_Next = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: When you allocate are you: (1) adding the header to the requested block size (2) allocating a block with at least new total size and (3) returning the (allocated address incremented by  the header size) to the caller?  When deallocating you subtract the header size from the addressed passed by the caller.  You can now use the header + block for bookkeeping of the blocks on the free chain.

Comment: Yea I search for a block with enough size to hold a header and the requested size but also I make sure that it has enough size for the allocated block to be aligned and the header behind it, like in my example so for example the a memory block expending the region between `10-22` (in decimal) while having enough space to hold a double (size 8) it can't hold it in an aligned address because the address returned would have to be 16 and 16 + 8 = 24 and it goes beyond this memory block. Another example is memory block expending region between `16-24` (in decimal)

Comment: while having enough space to hold a double (size 8) and also keeping it aligned at address 16, we cant store the header behind it at address 12-16 because that's out of the block memory region.

Answer (score 1):

This is because allocators usually return pointers to memory blocks that are suitably aligned for any scalar type. So, no need to pass alignment into allocator interface, e.g.

```
void* malloc(size_t size)
```

Usually, blocks are aligned by 8 bytes (x32) and 16 bytes (x64). A special type was added to C++11 to get that value:

```
alignof(std::max_align_t)
```

So, it is enough to align **both** header and payload by that value.

Assuming

```
alignof(std::max_align_t) == 2 * sizeof(size_t)
```

As your header size is `sizeof(size_t)`, but header and payload are aligned by `2*sizeof(size_t)`, there will be unused padding between the header and payload.

One of the way of using this padding is keeping previous block size. It simplifies unused blocks coalescing. Commonly used `glibc` allocator has the following chunk header structure:

```
struct Header {
  std::size_t prevSize;
  std::size_t size;
};
```

As a header and a payload are aligned by `2*sizeof(size_t)`, least significant bits of `size` can be used to keep bit flags like `unused` etc.

Anyway, your intention is to use header `sizeof(size_t)` long and reuse this padding for payload that doesn't require max alignment.

The only thing you should guarantee to do that is to **ALWAYS** align header by max alignment (`2*sizeof(size_t)`). This is crucial. In that case you can always convert payload pointer (aligned by `N <= 2*sizeof(size_t)`) to header pointer, because it has max possible alignment.

Something like that:

```
const auto ALIGN = alignof(std::max_align_t);

void* getHeaderPtr(void* ptr)
{
  intptr_t offset = (intptr_t)ptr % ALIGN;
  offset = offset ? offset : ALIGN;
  return (uint8_t*)ptr - offset;
}
```

Sure, you need to use bit arithmetics to get rid of `%` and branching, so treat it as a pseudocode.

Comment: While this is possible to align to cpu word size I think passing on alignment is easy enough and could save some wasted space of fragmentation  if everything is aligned to the cpu word size. That's why I chose to pass alignment to `Allocate`

Comment: @Jorayen Alignment by word size is not enough, that's why 16 byte alignment is used on x64, but anyway, I got you intention, and updated the answer.

Comment: Yea sorry meant to say to allocate on alignment of `max_align_t` not cpu word size.

About your updated answer, I still think we're talking about different things unless I'm wrong. You talk about minimizing memory wasted on metadata (while this could be the case if I were to always have header of size `max_align_t`. But as I choose not to and just have header defined as `std::size_t` holding the amount of allocated block, I'm talking about the wasted memory caused by the alignment of the header so to fit it exactly before the allocated block like in my question where you can see

Comment: 4 bytes left outside and even when the deallocation picks this memory region there's no way to retrieve these 4 bytes as the starting of a block inside the free list.

Comment: Great last update is more what I meant.
I found a way I can keep the header only `sizeof(Header) == sizeof(std::size_t)` while also keeping Header and Payload alignment to their natural alignment and not the alignment of `std::max_align_t`, this way I can keep Header size to minimum and padding to minimum leading to less internal fragmentation. I'll shortly post it and tell me what you think.

Answer (score 1):

Oh hey, a problem I had to solve in my job.

Let's start with a few assumptions and make a choice.

First, we'll assume we're on a platform that does not support unaligned accesses, like MIPS or ARM. Second, we'll assume whatever allocator is giving us real blocks of RAM is giving them without any alignment (or an alignment of 1 byte). Third, we'll assume there's no operating system around to double check our alignments, our allocations, or our memory borders (i.e. we're flying solo here).

Next, we'll choose our *natural alignment*, the amount we will align any new blocks we allocate by default. This is typically the size of our header structure, as we don't need to deal with edge cases where the alignment of the user block is less than our structure size but greater than our natural alignment. For the purposes of this example, I'll define the header to be the following:

```
struct AllocationHeader
{
    struct ListEntry* pNext;
    struct ListEntry* pPrev;
    uint32 Size;
    uint8 Alignment;
    uint8 Adjustment;
    uint16 Flags;
};
```

This structure has a size of 16 bytes, so any block we allocate from this allocator will guarantee an alignment of at least 16 bytes. Worth noting that no matter what your header size is, the algorithms involved are the same.

Now, on to the allocation.

First step is actually to start with *deallocation*, as this will inform how we structure our header and how we actually need to allocate our memory.

To deallocate a block of memory allocated by our system, we need to recover both the original block address and the block header. The header is fairly easy - just subtract the size of the header from the user block address:

```
AllocationHeader* pHeader = (AllocationHeader*)(((uint8*)UserPtr) - sizeof(AllocationHeader));
```

This gives us our header information, which we can then use as we see fit.

Second step is to recover the original block address from the header. This is given by our `Adjustment` member.

As you correctly noted, to have a block alignment that is equivalent to what the user wants, we need to adjust our allocation header address by at most `max(UserAlignment, NaturalAlignment) - 1` bytes. Upon allocation, we need to store this value in the header of the block, otherwise we cannot recover the original allocation address provided by the lower level allocator.

Once we have the Adjustment value, we can go ahead and recover the original block address:

```
uint8 Adjustment = pHeader->Adjustment;
uint8* BlockPointer = ((uint8*)pHeader) - Adjustment;
```

So the trick now is going to be computing the adjustment value.

To do this, we do the following steps in our allocation function:

1. Allocate a block of memory the same size as our user block plus the size of our header and the user's alignment, if it's larger than our header.

```
uint8 ActualAlignment = max(NaturalAlignment, UserAlignment);
uint32 BlockSize = UserSize + sizeof(AllocationHeader) + ActualAlignment;
uint8* pRawBlock = ::operator new(BlockSize);
```

2. Check the address against the actual alignment to produce an offset from our ideal alignment.

```
uint8 Offset = ((uintptr)pRawBlock) & (ActualAlignment - 1);
```

3. Compute the Adjustment value based on the offset and the actual alignment.

```
uint8 Adjustment = (((ActualAlignment - Offset) - NaturalAlignment) & (ActualAlignment - 1));
```

This expression seems... odd. After all, if we're allocating a block aligned to 32 bytes, and our offset is 26 bytes, when we subtract the natural alignment of 16, we end up with -10, which doesn't make sense as an alignment. The AND by `ActualAlignment - 1` fixes this by masking off the top most bits, resulting in 22, the number of bytes we need to add to the original address to ensure not only that our header is aligned properly, but the structure we are allocating will have the correct alignment as well.

Let's walk through our previous example, and check the resultant addresses as well.

Our address had an offset of 26 bytes from the ideal alignment. Plugging that value into our expression yields:

```
Adjustment = ((32 - 26) - 16) & 31

Adjustment = ((6) - 16) & 31
Adjustment = (-10) & 31
Adjustment = 0xF6 & 0x1F
Adjustment = 0x16
Adjustment = 22
```

If we then add that adjustment value to our original offset, we get:

```
pAllocationHeader = (26 + 22) = 48
pUserBlock = pAllocationHeader + 16 = 48 + 16 = 64
```

Both the Allocation header and user block are now properly aligned, and we can continue.

4. Fill in the allocation header and return the user block.

```
pAllocationHeader = (AllocationHeader*)(pRawBlock + Adjustment);
pAllocationHeader->Size = BlockSize;
pAllocationHeader->Alignment = ActualAlignment;
pAllocationHeader->Adjustment = Adjustment;
AddToAllocatedList(pAllocationHeader);
return (uint8*)(((uint8*)pAllocationHeader) + sizeof(AllocationHeader));
```

The most important piece here is keeping track of the adjustment value. Everything else in my example structure is for bookkeeping (i.e. assuming we're the only allocator), but the `Adjustment` member needs to be stored somewhere in the block metadata, otherwise you will never be able to free the block.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your way of achieving it.
I found a way I can keep the header only `sizeof(Header) == sizeof(std::size_t)` while also keeping Header and Payload alignment to their natural alignment and not the alignment of `std::max_align_t`, this way I can keep Header size to minimum and padding to minimum leading to less internal fragmentation. I'll shortly post it and tell me what you think.

Comment: Keep in mind that unless you can choose the starting address to match the alignment expected, you will always waste space equivalent to the alignment size when allocating. This is simply a consequence of the mathematics behind the alignment process.

Comment: yea I understand, maybe you could review my method on my answer posted. I tried to keep Header size to minimum while keeping inner fragmentation to minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so here's my proposal idea, would love to hear feedback or maybe edge cases I haven't thought of.

With my idea we have a `Header` defined as follows:

```cpp
struct Header {
    std::size_t m_Size;
};
```

`Header` will occupy at most 8 bytes on x64 and 4 bytes on x32.
Also I want to keep the `Header` and the payload aligned to their natural address and not to `std::max_align_t` because if we align to `std::max_align_t` we would most certainly properly align the `Header` and payload but we would also waste more bytes on internal fragmentation doing so.

The tricky part is that with alignment to `std::max_align_t` it's easy to get `Header` from payload address as we just subtract `2 * sizeof(std::size_t)` from the payload address and so we get to the `Header`.

But with aligning to `Header` and payload natural most smallest alignment we can't do that.
So what can we do?

Well, let me present you with 2 example cases and I'll present the way with each case:

1. Let's assume we're on x32 hence `sizeof(Header) = 4 = sizeof(std::size_t)` and `alignof(Header) = 4`. We'll assume the pool of the allocator is `100` bytes long and the starting address is at `0x0`:
   [image]
   Now we get an allocation request as follows:

```cpp
double* p = allocate(sizeof(double), alignof(double));
```

This means we request to allocate `8` bytes with alignment of `8`.
Now the first and only free block currently is a block with address of `0x0` with a size of `0x60` (`0x64 - sizeof(Header)`). Now for this block to be valid for our allocation it must have enough size for both **before payload padding** and **after payload padding**.

### What is before payload padding?

**before payload padding** is the padding between the end of the header and the start of the payload, in this case if `Header` can start on address `0x0` (the starting address of the block) since it align with `std::size_t` on x32 and the request allocated block must at-least start on address `0x8` to satisfy its alignment requirement then there's one block of size `std::size_t` between at address `0x4-0x7` that is the padding after the `Header` and before the payload such as that the payload could be properly aligned.

### What is after payload padding?

**after payload padding** is the padding that advances the head pointer of the free block list such as that it will **always** be aligned to to address that will be naturally aligned to the alignment of `Header`. So in our test case payload span addressed `0x8-0xf` that means there's no need for **after payload padding** since the next address `0x10` is aligned to `alignof(Header)` (remember we're on x32).

That means that the total `m_Size` of the header will be a sum of:

```
before payload padding + size + after payload padding
```

In our case this is:

```
4 + 8 + 0 = 12
```

And the memory layout after this allocation for our test case will be:

```
[X X X X Y Y Y Y Z Z Z Z Z Z Z Z __ __ __ ...]
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F 10 11 12 ...]
```

Where `X` is the `Header`, `Y` is the **before payload padding**, `Z` is the payload, and in that case there's no **after payload padding** so the head pointer to the next free block is set to address `0x10`.
[image]

2. Now let's look at an example where an **after payload padding** is used is used.
   We'll assume we're on x64 hence `sizeof(Header) = 8 = sizeof(std::size_t)` and `alignof(Header) = 8`. We'll assume the pool of the allocator is `100` bytes long and the starting address is at `0x0`:
   [image]
   Now we get an allocation request as follows:

```cpp
int32_t* p = allocate(sizeof(int32_t), alignof(int32_t));
```

This means we request to allocate `4` bytes with alignment of `4`.
Now if our header starts at `0x0` and ends at `0x7` then our payload will start at `0x8` and end at `0xB`, This time we don't need **before payload padding** since `0x8` is aligned address for our alignment but to make sure that the next free block starts at address that will satisfy the alignment of our `Header` which is `8` this time (remember we're on x64), we need an **after payload padding* of extra `4` bytes.
So this time our memory layout looks as follows:

```
[X X X X X X X X Y Y Y Y Z Z Z Z __ __ __ ...]
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F 10 11 12 ...]
```

Where `X` is the `Header`, `Y` is the payload, 'Z' is the **after payload padding** so the head pointer to the next free block is set to address `0x10` which is aligned for our `Header` to our convenience.
[image]

### How will we retrieve `Header` when deallocating?

For each block of size `std::size_t` that spans the addresses of **before payload padding** we'll set it to equal to `1` as a flag value to indicate we need to decrement another `sizeof(std::size_t)` bytes from the current pointer position until the value isn't equal to 1. We can do this since we use the fact the **after payload padding** always adds size to the payload so that the next free block will be aligned to the alignment of `Header` thus making the `Header`'s `m_Size` always multiple of `2`. The added **before payload padding** to the `m_Size` is always a multiple of `std::size_t` so there's no way its addition will affect the result of `m_Size` in a way that will have it least significant bit set to `1`. So the job of **after payload padding** is not only make sure the alignment of `Header` is set for the next free block, but also ensures if we get request of weird size allocations like 1,3,5, etc.. that the least significant bit of the `Header`'s `m_Size` will not be set to `1`, thus leaving us the value `1` as a flag indicating we need to decrement the pointer in the deallocation routine to find the header.

Now how this translates into code:

```cpp
#include "FreeListAllocator.h"

#include <memory>
#include <cassert>

FreeListAllocator::FreeListAllocator(const std::size_t size, bool resizeable)
    : Allocator(size), m_Head(nullptr), m_Resizeable(resizeable)
{
    m_StartAddress = ::operator new(size);
    m_Head = reinterpret_cast<Chunk*>(m_StartAddress);
    m_Head->m_Size = size - sizeof(Header);
    m_Head->m_Next = nullptr;
}

FreeListAllocator::~FreeListAllocator()
{
    ::operator delete(m_StartAddress);
    m_StartAddress = nullptr;
}

void* FreeListAllocator::Allocate(const std::size_t size, const std::size_t alignment)
{
    Chunk* chunk = m_Head;
    void* currentAddress = reinterpret_cast<char*>(chunk) + sizeof(Header);
    std::size_t space = chunk->m_Size;
    std::align(alignment, size, currentAddress, space);
    std::size_t headerPadding = reinterpret_cast<char*>(currentAddress) - reinterpret_cast<char*>(chunk) - sizeof(Header);
    std::size_t sizePadding = size % sizeof(std::size_t) != 0 ? sizeof(std::size_t) - size % sizeof(std::size_t) : 0;
    while (headerPadding + size + sizePadding > chunk->m_Size)
    {
        chunk = chunk->m_Next;
        if (chunk == nullptr)
            break;
        currentAddress = reinterpret_cast<char*>(chunk) + sizeof(Header);
        space = chunk->m_Size;
        std::align(alignment, size, currentAddress, space);
        headerPadding = reinterpret_cast<char*>(currentAddress) - reinterpret_cast<char*>(chunk) - sizeof(Header);
    }

    if (chunk == nullptr)
        return nullptr;

    m_Head = reinterpret_cast<Chunk*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(chunk) + sizeof(Header) + headerPadding + size + sizePadding);
    m_Head->m_Size = chunk->m_Size - (headerPadding + size + sizePadding + sizeof(Header));
    m_Head->m_Next = nullptr;

    for (std::size_t i = headerPadding; i > 0; i -= sizeof(std::size_t))
    {
        *reinterpret_cast<std::size_t*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(currentAddress) - i) = 1;
    }

    Header* header = reinterpret_cast<Header*>(chunk);
    header->m_Size = headerPadding + size + sizePadding;

    return reinterpret_cast<char*>(chunk) + sizeof(Header) + headerPadding;
}

void FreeListAllocator::Deallocate(void* ptr)
{
    Header* header = reinterpret_cast<Header*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(ptr) - sizeof(Header));
    while (header->m_Size == 1)
    {
        header = reinterpret_cast<Header*>(reinterpret_cast<std::size_t*>(header) - 1);
    }

    Chunk* chunk = reinterpret_cast<Chunk*>(header);
    chunk->m_Size = header->m_Size;
    chunk->m_Next = m_Head;
    m_Head = chunk;
}

void FreeListAllocator::Reset()
{
    m_Head = reinterpret_cast<Chunk*>(m_StartAddress);
    m_Head->m_Size = m_Size - sizeof(Header);
    m_Head->m_Next = nullptr;
}
```

Now with this we keep `Header` and payload properly aligned to **their** natural alignment and not the alignment of `std::max_alignment_t` thus making internal fragmentation lower, and also making `sizeof(Header)` potentially smaller without storing any extra info.

I can't guarantee this to work, I've tested it and run a few test cases and it's seems correct. Would love to hear your thoughts on this.